# Why after login in my site again I can see login page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a question.
1. in Django I created a login page after login successfully. If I enter /accounts/login again I can see this url and I can login again.
How can disable login page after that user was login and if user enter url for login page get another page?

**views.py**

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("home")
        else :
            messages.error(request, "Bad username or password")

    return render(request, "login.html", context={})
```

tnx for help

Comment: i checked two projects in github and those have this problem.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for me yes i have to know all of this for job interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "disable" it, by adding a check that verifies if the user is already authenticated, and then redirect it to somewhere else, like:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect("home")
        else :
            messages.error(request,"Bad username or password")

    return render(request,"login.html",context={})
```

So the `if` statement checks if the user is authenticated (logged in), and if so, then we return a HTTP redirect response to a view (here `'home'`).

In Django versions before [django-1.10](/questions/tagged/django-1.10), the check is `request.user.is_authenticated()` (so the method has to be *called*), but since [django-1.10](/questions/tagged/django-1.10) this is a property.

But I would not call it a (security) problem. One could also see it as a feature, and for instance log in to another account.